# Calculator Program in C#

Tags: c#, xaml, calculator

I am currently doing a pretty simple calculator program in C# and I have most of the program working fine as in the add,subtract,multiply and divide functions work fine, although the problem I have is that the decimal point isn't working correctly. The error is that when I add two numbers with a decimal it doesn't work correctly. 
                                                         I.e if I add 20 and .5 the result will be 20.5 BUT if I add 20 and 1.5 the answer will also be 20.5. I believe this is because, due to the way my code is written, the calculator will disregard the number 1 of the 1.5 (see my code below as I believe you guys may know how to fix this). Any help with resolving this issue would be appreciated.

(MainPage.xaml code)

```
    <phone:PhoneApplicationPage 
x:Class="Calculator.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignWidth="480" d:DesignHeight="768"
FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
SupportedOrientations="Portrait" Orientation="Portrait"
shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True">

<!--LayoutRoot is the root grid where all page content is placed-->
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <!--TitlePanel contains the name of the application and page title-->
    <StackPanel x:Name="TitlePanel" Grid.Row="0" Margin="12,17,0,28">
        <TextBlock x:Name="ApplicationTitle" Text="Jason Lynch" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="PageTitle" Text="Calculator" Margin="9,-7,0,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle1Style}"/>
    </StackPanel>

    <!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->
    <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
        <Button Content="=" Height="116" Margin="218,485,0,0" Name="btnEquals" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="127" Background="#FFFF550D" FontSize="56" Click="btnEquals_Click" />
        <Button Content="-" Height="116" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="323,485,6,0" Name="btnSubtract" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="127" FontSize="56" Padding="0,-25,0,0" Click="btnSubtract_Click" />
        <Button Content="0" Height="116" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="6,485,0,0" Name="btn0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="127" FontSize="56" Click="btn0_Click" />
        <Button Content="Clear" Height="73" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="112,485,0,0" Name="btnClear" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="127" FontSize="28" Background="#FF0008FF" Click="btnClear_Click"></Button>
        <Button Content="3" Height="116" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,389,111,0" Name="btn3" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="127" FontSize="56" Click="btn3_Click" />
        <Button Content="+" Height="116" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="323,389,0,0" Name="btnAdd" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="127" FontSize="56" Click="btnAdd_Click" />
        <Button Content="1" Height="116" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="6,389,0,0" Name="btn1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="127" FontSize="56" Click="btn1_Click" />
        <Button Content="2" Height="116" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="112,389,0,0" Name="btn2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="127" FontSize="56" Click="btn2_Click" />
        <Button Content="6" Height="116" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,294,111,0" Name="btn6" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="127" Click="button9_Click" FontSize="56" />
        <Button Content="x" Height="116" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,294,6,0" Name="btnMultiply" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="127" FontSize="56" Click="btnMultiply_Click" />
        <Button Content="4" Height="116" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="6,294,0,0" Name="btn4" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="127" FontSize="56" Click="btn4_Click" />
        <Button Content="5" Height="116" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="112,294,0,0" Name="btn5" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="127" FontSize="56" Click="btn5_Click" />
        <Button Content="9" Height="116" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="218,199,0,0" Name="btn9" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="127" FontSize="56" Click="btn9_Click" />
        <Button Content="÷" Height="116" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="323,199,0,0" Name="btnDivide" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="127" FontSize="56" Click="btnDivide_Click" />
        <Button Content="7" Height="116" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="6,199,0,0" Name="btn7" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="127" FontSize="56" Click="btn7_Click" />
        <Button Content="8" Height="116" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="112,199,0,0" Name="btn8" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="127" FontSize="56" Click="btn8_Click" />
        <TextBox Height="72" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,65,0,0" Name="resultTxtBox" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="460" />
        <TextBlock Height="53" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="169,26,0,0" Name="textBlock1" Text="Result" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="36" />
        <Button Content="." Height="68" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="112,533,0,0" Name="btnDecimalPoint" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="127" Click="btnDecimalPoint_Click" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" />
    </Grid>
</Grid>

<!--Sample code showing usage of ApplicationBar-->
<!--<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
    <shell:ApplicationBar IsVisible="True" IsMenuEnabled="True">
        <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton IconUri="/Images/appbar_button1.png" Text="Button 1"/>
        <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton IconUri="/Images/appbar_button2.png" Text="Button 2"/>
        <shell:ApplicationBar.MenuItems>
            <shell:ApplicationBarMenuItem Text="MenuItem 1"/>
            <shell:ApplicationBarMenuItem Text="MenuItem 2"/>
        </shell:ApplicationBar.MenuItems>
    </shell:ApplicationBar>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>-->
```

(MainPage.xaml.cs code)

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Net;
    using System.Windows;
    using System.Windows.Controls;
    using System.Windows.Documents;
    using System.Windows.Input;
    using System.Windows.Media;
    using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
    using System.Windows.Shapes;
    using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;

    namespace Calculator
    {
         public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
         {
             // Constructor
             public MainPage()
             {
                 InitializeComponent();
             }

             private double total1 = 0;
             private double total2 = 0;
             bool plusButtonClicked = false;
             bool minusButtonClicked = false;
             bool multiplyButtonClicked = false;
             bool divideButtonClicked = false;


             private void btn0_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
             {
                 resultTxtBox.Text = resultTxtBox.Text + "0";
             }

             private void btn1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
             {
                 resultTxtBox.Text = resultTxtBox.Text + "1";
             }

             private void btn2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
             {
                 resultTxtBox.Text = resultTxtBox.Text + "2";
             }

            private void btn3_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
            {
                 resultTxtBox.Text = resultTxtBox.Text + "3";
            }

            private void btn4_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
            {
                 resultTxtBox.Text = resultTxtBox.Text + "4";
            }

            private void btn5_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
            {
                 resultTxtBox.Text = resultTxtBox.Text + "5";
            }

            //MESSED UP BUTTON *** button9 == btn6 
            private void button9_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
            {
                 resultTxtBox.Text = resultTxtBox.Text + "6";
            }

            private void btn7_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
            {
                 resultTxtBox.Text = resultTxtBox.Text + "7";
            }

            private void btn8_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
            {
                resultTxtBox.Text = resultTxtBox.Text + "8";
            }

            private void btn9_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
            {
                resultTxtBox.Text = resultTxtBox.Text + "9";
            }

            private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
            {
                total1 = total1 += double.Parse(resultTxtBox.Text);
                resultTxtBox.Text = "";

                plusButtonClicked = true;
                minusButtonClicked = false;
                multiplyButtonClicked = false;
                divideButtonClicked = false;
            }

            private void btnSubtract_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
            {
                total1 = total1 + double.Parse(resultTxtBox.Text);
                resultTxtBox.Text = "";

                plusButtonClicked = false;
                minusButtonClicked = true;
                multiplyButtonClicked = false;
                divideButtonClicked = false;
            }

            private void btnMultiply_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
            {
                total1 = total1 + double.Parse(resultTxtBox.Text);
                resultTxtBox.Text = "";

                plusButtonClicked = false;
                minusButtonClicked = false;
                multiplyButtonClicked = true;
                divideButtonClicked = false;
           }

           private void btnDivide_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
           {
               total1 = total1 + double.Parse(resultTxtBox.Text);
               resultTxtBox.Text = "";

               plusButtonClicked = false;
               minusButtonClicked = false;
               multiplyButtonClicked = false;
               divideButtonClicked = true;
          }

          private void btnEquals_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
          {
              if (plusButtonClicked == true)
              {
                  total2 = total1 + double.Parse(resultTxtBox.Text);
                  resultTxtBox.Text = total2.ToString();
                  total1 = 0;
              }
             else if (minusButtonClicked == true)
             {
                  total2 = total1 - double.Parse(resultTxtBox.Text);
                  resultTxtBox.Text = total2.ToString();
                  total1 = 0;
             }
             else if (multiplyButtonClicked == true)
             {
                  total2 = total1 * double.Parse(resultTxtBox.Text);
                  resultTxtBox.Text = total2.ToString();
                  total1 = 0;
             }
             else if (divideButtonClicked == true)
             {
                  total2 = total1 / double.Parse(resultTxtBox.Text);
                  resultTxtBox.Text = total2.ToString();
                  total1 = 0;
             }
         }

         private void btnClear_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
         {
              resultTxtBox.Text = "";
         }

         private void btnDecimalPoint_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
         {
              resultTxtBox.Text = ".";
         }

    }
}
```

And finally here is a screencap of my calculator app >> http://gyazo.com/717b396e32b39d4a42e91ad9cf67cdef

Thanks for any help in advance,
Jason.

Comment: It seems to be related to the DecimalPoint_Click method. I'll try and get back

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to change

```
private void btnDecimalPoint_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    resultTxtBox.Text = ",";
}
```

with

```
private void btnDecimalPoint_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    resultTxtBox.Text += ",";
}
```

Comment: Thanks you for your help Akrem, this was the fix that I needed :)

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you don't have to write

```
 resultTxtBox.Text = resultTxtBox.Text + "8";
```

each time. Simply use

```
 resultTxtBox.Text += "8";
```

which is the same. It's much more readable, in my opinion.

Second, the line

```
total1 = total1 += double.Parse(resultTxtBox.Text);
```

is redundant.

```
total1 += double.Parse(resultTxtBox.Text);
```

is the same result. ;)

Third, the code for your decimal point reads

```
private void btnDecimalPoint_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    resultTxtBox.Text = ".";
}
```

So you replace the text in the `resultTxtBox.Text` with the decimal point. So I cannot imagine how you could write `1.5` in the first place, since the 1 would be removed from the Textbox once you click on the decimal point button.

Comment: Thanks for the advice on the code which needs fixing/refining. Although in your opinion how would you get the decimal point to work in this calculator as this was the problem I was having and I haven't been able to find a working fix for the decimal point button